# LAN with around 10 Computers loses internet connection

Tags: networking, local-area-network

We have around 10 computers in our private LAN. There is currently 3 routers and one big swich connecting all the computers. 2 of the routers had there DHCP disconnected in the beginning.

In the beginning we started to experience that it was hard to connect to homepages, that we needed to refresh the page a couple of times before it got connected, while services like skype, msn and the likes that keep up a connection (or maybe because they are using different ports) usually don't experience problems.

Other times it is impossible to connect to the internet and everything disconnects.

This can last for 20 minuttes or severel hours.

We are able to connect to each other, even the router, but without internet. When we log on the router it tells us it have internet.

Sometimes it helps to restart the routers, yesterday we tried to enable the 2 routers DHCP again and then make 2 subnets (That also worked for 24 hours). We have checked if this appears when a certain computer logs on (in case there is one computer with some malware) but there does not seem to be any pattern. We also checked if the routing table got filled up, but that was not the case.

We also had this problem with our last "Main" router (the one that is connected to the internet) and the current one is only one week old.

Does anyone have any suggestions to how we can find a solution to this problem?

Thanks for your time and hope you can help me

Comment: You might want to talk to your ISP.

Comment: Are you using static or dynamic IP addresses on the 10 computers?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the connection is stable directly from the router ? This will allow you to eliminate a lot of the gear from the issue.

That would be my first port of call for an issue like that for sure. Have you checked for latency or packet loss when your line is having issues ? Try a pathping to google and possibly one of these as well "www.pingtest.net"

I would go to your ISP or have a good look at your cabling after you have eliminated the switch from the proceedings.

I hope this helps.

Adam